# YII2 submit a form with a given model value

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

How to add default value to a model to save?

```
+--------------+--------------+-
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+-
| id           | int(11)      | ->auto increment
| grant        | double(12,2) |
| lcc          | double(12,2) |
| encoded_by   | int(11)      | ->foreign key from tbl_user
+--------------+--------------+-
```

here is the html form code.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'grant')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lcc')->textInput() ?>
```

the error I get on submit..

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ncddp`.`tbl_sp_bub`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_sp_bub_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`encoded_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)) The SQL being executed was:
>   INSERT INTO `tbl_sp_bub` (`grant`, `lcc`) VALUES (2, 2)

I understand that there should be a value for the encoded by which is the current users id.

I tried this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'grant')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lcc')->textInput() ?>
<? $model->encoded_by=yii::$app->user->identity->id ?>
```

and also this in the controller...

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new TblSpBub();
        $model->encoded_by=yii::$app->user->identity->id;//MY CODE
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in behavior to solve this called [BlameableBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html). Here is usage for your case. Add this to your model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            'createdByAttribute' => 'encoded_by',
            'updatedByAttribute' => false, // Set it to false if you need automatically update it on create only
        ],
    ];
}
```

And no need to handle it manually.